# Getting Contacts based on the GroupID in Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm having kind of a problem here, since I just startet developing for Android. I downloaded the sample from the official Android website "http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html", which is basically capable of retrieving an showing all the contacts from the phone. The feature I wanted to add is to just show contacts from a certain group like "Friends" (hardcoded).

As far as I narrowed it down I have to change the selection part

```
  final static String SELECTION =
            (Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) +
            "<>''" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1";
```

to something like this

```
  final static String SELECTION =
            Contacts.GroupID = "Friends";
```

which gives me errors, because it can't find the column.

I'm very eager to explore the potential of Android, but that one is giving me headache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There two ways for getting list of contacts of a group. First, I suppose you have GroupId and want to get related list of contacts.

```
String[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
            ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,
            ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE
    };
    return context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Groups._ID + "=" + groupId , null, null
    );
```

**Second way:**
I suppose you want to get contacts of specific group by a constants name. so, it's enough you change above codes:

```
context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + "='Friends'" , null, null
    );
```

Now you have necessary details from specific Group. Then you can fetch **list of Contact List**:

```
public static Cursor getContactsOfGroup(Group group) {
    // getting ids of contacts that are in this specific group
    String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "="
            + group.id + " AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE + "='"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

    Cursor query = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID
            }, where, null, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

    String ids = "";
    for (query.moveToFirst(); !query.isAfterLast(); query.moveToNext()) {
        ids += "," + query.getString(0);
    }
    if (ids.length() > 0) {
        ids = ids.substring(1);
    }

    // getting all of information of contacts. it fetches all of number from every one
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            "_id",
            "contact_id",
            "lookup",
            "display_name",
            "data1",
            "photo_id",
            "data2", // number type: 1:home, 2:mobile, 3: work, else : other
    };
    String selection = "mimetype ='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"
            + " AND account_name='" + group.accountName + "' AND account_type='" + group.accountType + "'"
            + " AND contact_id in (" + ids + ")";

    return context.getContentResolver().query(BASE_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
}
```

Notice, in second fetch in this method we check **accountName** and **accountType** to be sure this record is related this group, because may be there are some records that stored for another Apps like *WhatsApp*. and we don't like get those. ok?

I hope will useful for you.